# $div(z)=0\Leftrightarrow z\in k$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm reading [algebraic curves book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) from Fulton and I didn't understand this corollary on page 98:

[image]

Why $\deg(div(z-\lambda_0))\gt 0$? and why is this a contradiction?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By construction $z-\lambda_0$ is a rational function vanishing at $p$ but with no poles, so $\operatorname{div}(z-\lambda_0)$ is an effective divisor which contains the term $p$ with coefficient at least 1. The degree $\operatorname{deg}(\operatorname{div}(z-\lambda_0))$ is obtained by adding up all the coefficients in the divisor, so this is a sum of non-negative terms with at least one nonzero, hence it is strictly bigger than 0.

It's hard to say for sure why it's a contradiction unless you tell us what the preceding result says (I'm not going to follow the link), but presumably it says that the divisor of any rational function on a  curve has degree 0. But we just exhibited a divisor of a rational function with strictly positive degree.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have just one question, why is $z-\lambda_0$ a rational function? in another words, I know that $z=f/g$ such that $f,g$ are residues forms in $\Gamma_h(V)$, so why is $z-\lambda_0=f/g-\lambda_0$ a rational function?

Comment: Any constant is a rational function; rational functions are a _field_, so you can add them. It's probably a good idea for you to work out those details yourself.